# Open a pdf file in browser window using a link?

Tags: html

I have an image icon, that when a user clicks on it I would like the pdf file associated with that image to open the pdf file in a new window or preferably a new tab.  However, what I am getting is simply a download, which is not what I need.  All of the attempts below downloads the pdf file.

I have tried the following:

attempt-1

```
 <a href="linkToPDFFile"><img src="imgPath"></a>
```

attempt-2

```
 <img src="imgPath" onclick="window.open('linkToPDFFile')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `target` attribute that open a pdf in new tab

```
 <a href="linkToPDFFile" target="_blank"><img src="imgPath"></a>
```

Try [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ydozbqc/)